# Swagger2 com SpringBoot. Como separar a documentação do código-fonte?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou documentando as APIs de um projeto Spring Boot utilizando o Swagger2.

Existem duas formas de documentar: utilizando um arquivo de texto (JSON ou YML) ou utilizar anotações.
O problema de utilizar um arquivo de texto é a dificuldade em dar manutenção, pois o arquivo ficará cada vez maior, já utilizando anotações acaba poluindo o código-fonte.

Alguém sabe se existe uma forma de criar um segundo projeto com apenas a documentação? Dessa forma seria possível separa a documentação do código-fonte.

Comment: Por que não gosta da anotação, para mim é ideal justamente porque o programador em questao ao crira um metodo ele ja documenta na hora, não esquece, não tem que parar de fazer o que estiver fazendo para documentar depois. Pode ser um pouco de preciosismo seu.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde sei há as duas formas que você citou.

1 - Adição da dependência do Swagger no pom.xml do seu projeto Spring Boot;

2 - Criação de um arquivo YAML/JSON e usar em uma ferramenta externa(A Mulesoft tem um editor de YAML/RAML muito bom);

Uma outra alternativa(acho que não é muito trivial) é que você poderia criar uma classe se configuração em um outro projeto Spring boot e documentar tudo lá, e esse projeto "documentação" ser uma dependência a ser anotada no pom.xml do seu projeto, mas acho que não é costumeira esa prática.

Answer (score 0):

O swagger possui uma estrutura verborrágica para escrever contratos. As estratégias que visam focar no desenho da API (API First) visão criar um repositório para se realizar o desenho da API, geralmente escrevendo no formato YAML (mais enxuto).

A partir do contrato desenhado utilizam uma ferramenta swagger-codegen para gerar o scaffolding do projeto.

A estratégia seria focar numa automação nascendo a partir do contrato onde o scaffolding, sandbox e swagger-ui são gerados e disponibilizados já para consumo.

Se quiser outra alternativa para escrever contrato com um padrão menos verborrágico o [RAML (RESTful API Modeling Language)](https://raml.org/) é interessante. A desvantagem do RAML se diz quando ao seu ferramental disponível em relação ao swagger.